# Get UUID of a device on which a given file is stored, on *NIX systems using C

Tags: c, unix, device, uuid

Given: The path of a file on a UNIX file system

How can I get the UUID of the device it is stored on, possibly with a library call from C, in a way that is the most portable amongst UNIX like system (including OS X)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call **int stat(const char *path, struct stat *buf)** and the buf->st_dev will give to you the device's ID.
stat() is POSIX.1.